# CSS Border-Image / Frame Like Overlay

Tags: html, css, border-image

Howdy!
How would you go about creating a border image which overlays all page content without interfering with it?

I figured I would need to use the personal [border image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) property, but this doesn't seem to be able to be applied to content below without directly affecting it.

Is there a way to set the height of an absolute positioned frame to 100% of content height, or would that overlay and obstruct all content interaction with a transparent background...
Ideas?

Comment: have you tryed your absolute overlay ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the border-image to a pseudo-element, that doesn't interfere with the rest of the page.

```css
body {
  margin: 35px;
}
body:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  border: 21px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1mpM.png') 21 21 round;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the web page</h1>
<p>This is the content of the web page.</p>
```

Of course you will need a large margin on the `body` to keep the text away from the border, but other than that, the text and the border don't interact.